# How do I get the index of an array which I don't know?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, indexing

### The Task

#### Method:

```
public int indexOfTarget (int[] values, int target)
```

#### Description:

Compulsory Exercise 8) Complete the indexOfTarget method which is passed two parameters: an array of ints(values) and an int(target). The method returns the index position within the array of the first occurrence of the specified integer target. If target occurs in the array, then the index of the first such occurrence is returned.

For example, if the input array is
{3, 7, 2, 4} and the target is 7

the method returns 1

If no such integer occurs in this array, then -1 is returned.

An example:
indexOfTarget({3, 7, 2, 4}, 7)` should return 1.

## So Far I Have Written:

```
public int indexOfTarget (int[] values, int target) {
int targetMatch=-1;
for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
if(values[i]==target){
targetMatch=values[i];
}
}
return targetMatch;
}
```

## The Results of CodeWrite Errors

[image: my results]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/7892260b1721b8623ba4ac4477d8b12f.png))</sub>

Comment: try think over it first or debug.

Comment: @Alya'a Gamal comment on my answer is worth a gander there, Natalie

Answer (score 2):

You want `targetMatch = i;` not `targetMatch=values[i];`

You should be saving the index, not the value.

I would also add `break;` inside the `if` statement, immediately after you set the value of `targetMatch`

Answer (score 2):

you should have `targetMatch = i` instead.  You want the index value, not the value of the array at that index.

Comment: That made all of the trials work except for:
input:{1, 4, 20, 0, 4, 5, 4},target: 4 expected:1 actual:6 result: FAIL

Comment: @NatalieCorfe-Tan I fixed that problem in my answer

Comment: so what remains is to leave the for loop once you have successfully entered the if block.  If you don't exit the for loop, you have the potential to enter the if block again and overwrite the index value, i.  Try searching for how to exit for loops :)

Comment: or instead of searching, have a look at @durron597's answer.  He gave you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Nice.  Glad we could help.  Does that all make sense?

Comment: you should consider writing out an answer @Alya'a Gamal.  I think you have the ability to write a very informative post that people can refer to.

Comment: @JakeSmith: aha sure i can, but i wrote there to edit your answer and make it completely , that's it , sooooooo sorry for that , and it's not impotent to write it as an answer

Comment: Oh don't be sorry, I appreciate you helping me with my answer.  I just figured that since you were providing more support to his question, you could provide an answer that most likely would be accepted as the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

This java code should work for all scenarios when the array contains a valid int value. * is not a valid int value.

```
public class Program
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int[] values= {3, 7, 2, 4};
    int target = 7;
    int position = indexOfTarget(values,target);
    if(position>-1)
    System.out.println("Pass");
    else
    System.out.println("Fail");
    }

public static int indexOfTarget (int[] values, int target) {
int targetMatch=-1;
for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
if(values[i]==target){
targetMatch=i;
return i;
}
}
    return targetMatch;
    }
}
```